# Double integral for area surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Use double integral to calculate the area of the surface. The part of the cylindrical surfaces $\ x^2$ +$\ z^2$ = 4, that lies above the region 0 $\leq$ x $\leq$ 2  and 0 $\leq$ y $\leq$ x

how do i solve this?

Comment: i have tried the formula for surface area in polar coordinates with upper limits pi/4 and 2, lower limits 0 and 0

Comment: This surface is unbounded and has infinite area.

Comment: Are you sure this is not supposed to be $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$? Yves is correct, otherwise, you just have a portion of the cylinder (represented by the circle $r=2$ in every plane parallel to the $xy-$plane) "going up forever" above this region.

Comment: Well, $x^2+y^2=4$ is cylindrical. I would expect a letter $z$ somewhere in the constraint.

Comment: I have copied exactly what the book says, the answer key says 4 square units

Comment: Oh my god, i have actually mistaken z^2 for y^2, my apologies. Even though ive rechecked the question several times i manage to make that miss. editing the question now.